Por que no se me muestran las flechas ni los nombres en tikz?
Tengo el siguiente código
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata,
                quotes,
                positioning
                }

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \node (n1) at (0,0) {ET1};
  \node (n2) at (3,4)  {AP2};
  \node (n3) at (8,4)  {PA3};
  \node (n4) at (11,0) {CR5};
  \node (n5) at (8,-4)  {CL6};
  \node (n6) at (3,-4)  {PC7};
  \node (n7) at (5.5,0)  {OD8};


 
\path (n1) edge [loop  left,"$a$"] ()
      (n2) edge [loop  above,"$a$"] ()
      (n3) edge [loop  above,"$a$"] ()
      (n5) edge [loop  below,"$a$"] ()
      (n6) edge [loop  below,"$a$"] ()
      
      
      (n1) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n2)
      (n2) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n3)
      (n3) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n4)
      (n4) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n5)
      (n5) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n7)
      (n7) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n5)
      (n5) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n6)
      (n4) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n4)
      (n6) edge [bend left,"$b$"] (n1);

\end{tikzpicture}

El código genera unos nodos que quisiera unir mediante flechas que puedan tener contenido, aquí seria "a" y "b" pero espero ponerle algo como "1111/110", como podría solucionar ese problema de que no me plotea el teto ni las puntas de las flechas?
Además como podría colorear los círculos con un color suave?

lo resolví con este enlace.
VINCULO
Quedo atento por si alguien sabe como rellenar solo los circulos. saludos!

Pon siempre un breve resumen del contenido del enlace en la respuesta. Piénsalo: si un día el enlace cae, se perderá parte esencial de la respuesta, además de que futuros usuarios con un problema similar quedarán sin saber qué respondió a tu pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
